# Trying to write a program that calculates the amount of days a person is from they date of birth(19880101) using GregorianCalander class in Java

Tags: java

I cannot for the life of me get my head around how I should write this program.

The program
The task is to write a Java program that calculates how many days old a person is. The program will ask a user for birth data that the user enters in the form YYYYMMDD (as an integer, not a string). Subsequently, from the current date taken from your computer, see below) how many days old the person is, and this result is printed.

Programs dialog when you run the program looks like this:

When were you born? 19930102
Then you are today 7,707 days old.

Note - the program shall take into account any leap days.

**Limitation
The calculation of how many days old a person is to be done by your own code, not the practice in any existing date class.**

Today's date
To get the current date from the computer can GregorianCalendar class is used. When you create an object of that class is read computer time. You can then get the year, month and day of the object with the method get. How it works:

```
GregorianCalendar greg = new GregorianCalendar ();
int year = greg.get (Calendar.YEAR);
int month = greg.get (Calendar.MONTH);
int day = greg.get (Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

You will get a result for year, month and day. Note, however, that month is returned as a number 0-11, ie 0 for January, 1 for February, etc.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your programming exercises with us. I hope you have fun and learn a lot solving them **yourself**. If you have any **specific** implementation question, feel free to come back and ask it here properly (see the FAQs of the forum).

Answer (score 0):

I won't write any code, but here is an algorithm that should do this. I am not saying that this is efficient! But since the calculation is limited (no human being is 100000+.. years old) it can be used:

1st prompt the user to type his birthday in YYYYMMDD format as a STRING

2nd use substring to get YYYY MM DD (this should be allowed, I guess)

3rd convert YYYY MM and DD into integers

4th use the code you provided to get todays date

Let your algorithm assume a year has 365 days

5th calculate year (greg.get (Calendar.YEAR) MINUS YYYY

6th todays month - birth month: If negative then safe -MONTHS+DAYSINTHEMONTH in a variable ELSE +MONTHS*DAYSINTHEMONTH

7th calculate todays day - birth day: safe this in a value and add this to your final variable

8th now calculate ((todays year - birth year)*365)+(value of step 6, can be pos. or negative)+(value of step 7, can be pos. or negative)

Print out your answer to the console!

What you have to think of is how to get the exact amount of days in a month (which can be hard coded of course, since you are not allowed to use any classes at all).

Comment: Thanks! the problem is that the user is not allowed to enter the value as a String. It has to be Int, which makes the assignment tricky..